# Emacs function to open file [current date].tex

Tags: function, emacs, elisp

I'm trying to write an emacs function that uses the current date to create a file. I'm new to emacs and so I'm having trouble with variables and syntax. Here's what I have:

```
(defun daily ()
    (interactive)
    (let daily-name (format-time-string "%T"))
    (find-file (daily-name)))
```

I don't understand how emacs uses variables well enough to get it to set the time string as a variable and feed that variable into the find-file function. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To build on what others are saying:

```
(defun daily-tex-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((daily-name (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")))
    (find-file (expand-file-name (concat "~/" daily-name ".tex")))))
```

Main differences:

- Different format string, which gives date instead of time (which is what you want, I think)
- specifying the directory (`~/`) -- if you don't put this, you'll get files all over the place, depending on what the current working directory is at the moment you invoke the function
- better function name

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun daily ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((daily-name (format-time-string "%T")))
    (find-file (format "%s.tex" daily-name))))
```

Calling `M-x daily` now opens a file "12:34:56.tex".

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun daily ()     
  (interactive)     
  (let ((daily-name (format-time-string "%T")))
      (find-file (concat daily-name ".tex"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too few parentheses in some places, and too many in others.  This is the corrected version of your function:

```
(defun daily ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((daily-name (format-time-string "%T")))
    (find-file daily-name)))
```

Note in particular that the expression `(daily-name)` attempts to call a function by that name; to access the value of the variable `daily-name`, just write its name on its own, without parentheses.

Also note that in this particular case, you can do without a variable entirely:

```
(defun daily ()
  (interactive)
  (find-file (format-time-string "%T")))
```