# Emacs: Open file with date in title, insert text

Tags: emacs

I have a modified version of a script in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019581/emacs-function-to-open-file-current-date-tex), namely

```
(defun now ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((daily-name (format-time-string "%y%m%d_%H%M%S")))
    (find-file (format "/path/%s.org" daily-name))))
```

in my `.emacs`, but I would also like to insert a string before the cursor when the file is opened. I am completely unfamiliar with Emacs Lisp, so I have no clue how I would go about doing this. How would I do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Like this?  `(defun now () (interactive) (let ((daily-name (format-time-string "%y%m%d_%H%M%S"))) (find-file (format "/path/%s.org" daily-name)) (insert "hello-world")))`

Answer (score 0):

Page [*Inserting Today's Date*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InsertingTodaysDate) on EmacsWiki provides various ways to do what you request, from using a shell to using the Emacs calendar and using `format-time-string`.

Answer (score 0):

A very under used feature of emacs which I think is quite useful is 'tempo'. It has been around for years and there are various other packages, such as ysnippets, which can do similar.

Essentially, tempo allows you to define templates which can be inserted into files. These templates can have both static and dynamic content. I use a tempo template to insert a header at the top of my files which contains various information, including creation date and last modified date. Through using other emacs features, the last modified date gets updated every time the file is saved. Here is what I use. Note that I bind the tempo function to insert the template to f5, so all I have to do to insert the template is hit f5 when I create a new file. You could also automate this to insert the template whenever you open a new file of a specific type.

```
(require 'tempo)


(tempo-define-template "generic-header"
                       '((format "%s%s" comment-start comment-start)
                         "      Filename: "
                         (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)) 'n
                         (format "%s%s" comment-start comment-start)
                         " Creation Date: "
                         (format-time-string "%A, %d %B %Y %I:%M %p %Z") 'n
                         (format "%s%s" comment-start comment-start)
                         " Last Modified: "
                         (format-time-string "%A, %d %B %Y %I:%M %p %Z") 'n
                         (format "%s%s" comment-start comment-start)
                         "        Author: Tim Cross <theophilusx AT gmail.com>"
                         'n
                         (format "%s%s" comment-start comment-start)
                         "   Description:" 'n
                         (format "%s%s" comment-start comment-start) 'n
                         'n))

;;; Lets setup some key bindings.

(global-set-key [(f5)] 'tempo-template-generic-header)

(provide 'tx-template)
```

and here is the bit which does the updating of timestamps

```
(add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'time-stamp)

(setq time-stamp-active t)
(setq time-stamp-format "%:a, %02d %:b %:y %02I:%02M %#P %Z")
(setq time-stamp-start "\\(Time-stamp:[         ]+\\\\?[\"<]+\\|Last Modified:[ 
        ]\\)")
(setq time-stamp-end "\\\\?[\">]\\|$")
(setq time-stamp-line-limit 10)

(provide 'tx-timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Library [**`header2.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/header2.el) lets you (optionally) automatically insert a file header when you open a new file. You can customize what is in the header. Predefined fields you can choose from (you can easily define your own as well) include fields with timestamps (for which you can define the time/date format you want).

Besides inserting a header in a new file, the library can automatically *update* header fields that you choose - in particular, last-modified time/date fields.

Package `header2.el` is available at [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/header2.el) and from [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/header2).